# PHP - CURLOPT_CAPATH. Where a server has multiple certificates, will failing ones be ignored?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

Our supplier is renewing its TLS certificate.  They are sending their new one.  Then we will have two certificates for the same supplier in our CURLOPT_CAPATH directory.

On a "cutover date" (not yet fixed in stone) the supplier will stop accepting the earlier (not yet expired) certificate ... and start accepting only the newer certificate.

Will having both certificates in CURLOPT_CAPATH mean that curl will check certificates until it finds a successful one ?

*Carefully reading through descriptions of the setting CURLOPT_CAPATH I have not been able to find any reference to what 'alternative' certificates means, and how multiples for the same path/name are treated.*

Thank you for your help (in advance).

Comment: If at least one CA certificate if valid, then it's fine.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Is this problem even related to PHP itself?

Comment: Thanks Olivier and Nico ... it seems very much an `edge` situation, but is on a production server ... so I was trying to get ahead of things going wrong.  Of course, as you have noted Nico, setting curl to not need to verify the ssl certificate will not work.

Answer (score -3):

You can set curl to not need to verify the ssl certificate

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Why should that be a good idea?